# Blank screen on login to TestLink 1.9.7

Tags: testlink

I have installed TestLink version 1.9.7 in fresh installation using the automated mode.
When I log in to the login page I get the upper menu but the main body of the page is blank.
When I read the source, I see that indeed there are two frames, the upper frame points to navBar.php and loads but the main body points to mainPage.php but does not load.
If I try to go to mainPage.php manually it redirects to another page (I can see in the URL) but the page is again blank and absolutely nothing in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problems with a fresh installation of TestLink 1.9.8.

Removing the module php5-adodb fixed it for me - [post I wrote about it](http://kinoshita.eti.br/2013/10/27/missing-menus-in-new-installation-of-testlink.html)

Comment: This is not an answer and should have instead been posted as a comment.

Comment: Point taken. What should I do, move it to a comment (is that possible?) or maybe delete my comment?